# add multiple records in one field at once

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm making a recipes database where I have two tables, one for the recipes and one for the ingredients, and I have 6 ingredients. How can I add these 6 in one field at once? When I try to register it, I got this error message [message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1AW0.png)

the message means:

```
runtime error '3063':

duplicate output destination 'name_ing'
```

(by the way, sorry for the image not being in English)

in my SQL code I have just one thing, put in the `name_ing` in the ingredient table, the name of my ingredient from my form using the command: `CurrentDb.Execute`, here it is: [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7zU1.png) [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtp4H.png)

in the 'ingredients' table I have only it's ID and the ingredient name, and in the recipe table I have: name_recipe, `name_ingredient1, qtd_ing1, unit_ing1`, and these until 6

Comment: Code, including SQL statement, should be posted as formatted text, not image. Provide sample data as text tables.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is not valid.

Run the code inserting *one value* in *one field* for each ingredient. In other words: Run the command six times.